# SQL Select Statement Starting From Certain Row

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a SQL select statement that was working fine until I added a header to the page. When I remove the header it works again. How do I start from a certain row? I want to select everything from row 8 onwards. I tried adding a range to the Statement but it didn't work and not sure if it was right. The header is row 1 - 7 as shown in the image attached.

```vb
    Sub SortSchedule()

        Dim conn As New ADODB.connection
        
        conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & _
        ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"";"
        
        
        Dim sortQuery As String
        
        sortQuery = "Select [vrid],[route],[schedule_date],[vehicle_carrier],[actual_vehicle],[carrier_name],[orig_planned_yard_checkin_time],[orig_planned_yard_checkout_time],[dest_node],[orig_node] from [InboundOutbound$] where [orig_node] = 'Birmingham' or [orig_node] = 'Bristol' or [orig_node] = 'London' or [orig_node] = 'Newcastle' or [orig_node] = 'Exeter'"        
       
         
        Dim nrs As New ADODB.Recordset
        
        
        nrs.Open sortQuery, conn
        
        Dim wSht As Worksheet
        Set wSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sort")
        
        With wSht
        
        .Cells.clearContents
        For i = 0 To nrs.Fields.Count - 1
        .Cells(7, i + 1).Value = nrs.Fields(i).Name
        Next i
        .Range("A8").CopyFromRecordset nrs
        
        
        End With
        
        conn.Close

End Sub
```

[image: Header Image]

Answer (score 1):

- Assumes the field name (vrid, route etc.) in the 8th row on sheet `InboundOutbound`.

```vb
With Sheets("InboundOutbound")
    Dim dataRef As String
    dataRef = Application.Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("8:" & .Rows.Count)).Address(0, 0)
    sortQuery = "Select [vrid],[route],[schedule_date],[vehicle_carrier],[actual_vehicle],[carrier_name],[orig_planned_yard_checkin_time],[orig_planned_yard_checkout_time],[dest_node],[orig_node] from [InboundOutbound$" & dataRef & "] where [orig_node] = 'Birmingham' or [orig_node] = 'Bristol' or [orig_node] = 'London' or [orig_node] = 'Newcastle' or [orig_node] = 'Exeter'"      
End With
```

Comment: That worked a treat good sir, thank you